# Using Moq, How do you Mock a method that uses local variables

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

New to Moq and this is a very simple example.  I want to Mock the call to my "int smokeTest(int a, int b)" method which is used within my method "string getCode(int someID)".  Variables for smokeTest are declared and set within getCode.  The issue is when I mock the method call to smokeTest I always get a result of "0" within getCode but I want to see my predefined result of "20".  The only work around I've found is to overload the method and pass in all variables.  However, I do not want to do this because many of the methods I want to test declare and use local variables.  What's the best way to test this method using Moq?  Thanks

```
// Example A
public string getCode(int someID)
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    int z = _dataAccess.smokeTest(x, y);

    return _dataAccess.getCode(someID);
}

// NOTE: Doesn't work as wanted
[Test]
public void test_getCode_TestB()
{
    var x = It.IsAny<int>();
    var y = It.IsAny<int>();

    // NOTE: "20" is not returned, 0 is returned instead because local variables are used
    _mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.smokeTest(x, y)).Returns(20);
    _mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.getCode(234)).Returns("def345");

    var result = _businessLogic.getCode(234);

    Assert.IsTrue(result == "def345");
}

// Example B

// NOTE: Workaround - pass in variables
public string getCode(int someID, int a, int b)
{
    var c = _dataAccess.smokeTest(a, b);
    return _dataAccess.getCode(someID);
}       

[Test]
public void test_getCode_TestC()
{
    var x = It.IsAny<int>();
    var y = It.IsAny<int>();

    // NOTE: "20" is returned as wanted
    _mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.smokeTest(x, y)).Returns(20);
    _mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.getCode(234)).Returns("def345");

    var result = _businessLogic.getCode(234, x, y);
    Assert.IsTrue(result == "def345");
}
```

Comment: is it still works wrong after replace to var y?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will only work if you pass `It.IsAny<int>()` directly into the moq setup:

```
_mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.smokeTest(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(20);
```

I was browsing moq source code to found out that doing this:

```
int x = It.IsAny<int>();
int y = It.IsAny<int>();
_mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.smokeTest(x, y)).Returns(20);
```

will assigened x and y to be the deafult value of int which is 0, so your setup is equivalent to this:

```
_mockDataAccess.Setup(m => m.smokeTest(0, 0)).Returns(20);
```

this setup tells the moq to return 20 if the parameters are 0 and 0, otherwise it will return the deafult value of int which is 0 again. This is not the behavior you intended to create so you should not assigned `It.IsAny<int>()` into x and y before you pass them into the moq setup.
As @Rob comment indicates `It.IsAny<T>` is a kind of stub that you can pass into the moq setup, the setup method will know how to deal with it using [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx), but the value that this method actually returns is always the deafult of T. This is why we have to use this method always directly in the moq setup.

Comment: @rob23 I'm glad I could help, I edited my answer with more info about the probelm for your information.

Comment: Note that this is because of some trickery within the mocking library. `It.IsAny<T>()` is likely a stub which simply returns `default(T)`. However, we pass an expression tree into `Setup()` - which means `It.IsAny<T>` isn't really invoked by the library, and merely uses it as an instruction as to how to deal with the arguments

Comment: @Rob I read this code and I think that this is a great usage of expression trees and a great trick, but unfortunately it can also lead new users of the framework to deal with annoying bugs like this.

Comment: Seems like they could have thrown a NotSupportedException with a message explaining how to actually use the methods.